# Sonar 3.4 LDAP authentication with Active Directory - NullPointer exception

Tags: authentication, active-directory, sonarqube

I am trying to get Sonar to use LDAP authentication against Active Directory

I have the following settings

```
# LDAP Authentication
sonar.security.realm: LDAP
sonar.authenticator.class: org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapAuthenticator  
sonar.authenticator.createUsers: true
ldap.url: ldap://172.20.16.15:389
ldap.baseDn: DC=mycompany,DC=com  
ldap.bindDn: CN=myuser,OU=serviceaccounts,OU=My Group,DC=mycompany,DC=com  
ldap.bindPassword: password
ldap.loginAttribute: sAMAccountName
ldap.userObjectClass: user
# ldap.user.request: sAMAccountName={0}
```

However, I keep getting

```
ERROR rails  Error from external users provider: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I tried changing ldap.loginAttribute/ ldap.userObjectClass with ldap.user.request but that still does not work.

The sonar ldap plugin I have is 1.2.1. Please help me identify what is wrong with the config

I have used the same entries with ADExplorer to ensure that I can browse the AD and the same/similar settings work with Artifactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, looks like I was using some deprecated properties. Once I enabled debug on the plugin I was able to get useful info

Here is what worked for me with LDAP plugin 1.2.1 and sonar 3.4

```
sonar.security.realm: LDAP 
#sonar.authenticator.class: org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapAuthenticator  -- use above
sonar.authenticator.createUsers: true
ldap.url: ldap://server:389
ldap.user.baseDn: DC=mycompany,DC=com  
ldap.bindDn: CN=myuser,OU=serviceaccounts,OU=MyGroup,DC=mycompany,DC=com  
ldap.bindPassword: password
#ldap.user.objectClass: user -- use the ones below
#ldap.group.objectClass: group -- use the ones below
#ldap.group.memberAttribute: member --use the ones below
#ldap.user.loginAttribute: sAMAccountName -- use the ones below
ldap.group.request: (&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
ldap.user.request: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
```